# how to add users after signing in in devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise gem with multiple roles. after signing in the admin needs to add new users. how to do it using separate controller for adding new users using the same default model of devise gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are instructions for that here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface

Basically, you just add a 'users' controller and views, the same way you would for any other resource. There's a couple of gotchas though, covered in the link above.